# Keyboard won't open for EditText

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, androidx

I am developing a basic chat application and I have the following lines of code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText input = findViewById(R.id.input);
// Read the input field and push a new instance
// of ChatMessage to the Firebase database
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference()
        .push()
        .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                        .getCurrentUser())
                        .getDisplayName())
        );

// Clear the input
input.setText("");}
```

I have no errors and the app runs, but it sends blank texts and isn't giving an option to enter text. That is, the keyboard won't open. How can I resolve this?

Comment: can you also share the xml related to this EditText? 
maybe its not actual edit text?

Comment: after clear text, try this.
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

Comment: The last suggestion was helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try it to solve your problem:

**1.Make a small change to manifest file to solve it**

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    ... >
    </activity>
```

**2. Add these lines to editext**

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

**3. Also you can use it in your code**

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```